# Synaptics touchpad stops working randomly after suspend in MSI GS65

Tags: suspend, touchpad, synaptics, msi

I have an MSI GS65 8RF running Ubuntu 20.04 (but the problem has been experienced with previous versions) and pretty much everything works OK except the touchpad. The touchpad sometimes stops working after suspend/resume. I have gone through questions that report similar issues and they recommend basically remove/unload the **psmodule** and reload it again. I created the following script that I execute manually:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse

sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

but it does not seem to make a difference. So far what I do when the touchpad does not work after resuming is to run the script and suspend again until the touchpad starts working again. Sometimes it requires just one intent but sometimes I just give up and restart the laptop.

People with MSI GS65 does not seem to report this problem, I am wondering the following:

1. Am I the only one having this issue in this laptop?
2. If I am not the only one, then how you have "fixed" the issue?

One thing to add is that I tried Ubuntu with the mate desktop and the problem was much less frequent as resuming is much faster, so my guess is that this is related to the order in how ubuntu loads modules.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My workaround so far is to hibernate instead of suspend.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution, but unsure if it solves the problem completely:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add:

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

then run:

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**NOTE:** I am NOT using TLP (to save battery) and I have read cases where TLP may conflict with some devices when waking up after suspend.